# Sum rows with same product names but different values Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to SUM these values
[image: I'm trying to SUM these values]
And this is what happens after I run the macro. 
[image: And this is what happens after I run the macro.]
I'm having trouble with the following problem, I'm trying to build a macro to combine corresponding values in column A and then SUM the values in column B.

I've tried the following code, which deletes the duplicates in column A but does nothing or very little with column B.

```
Sub RemoveDupsAndSumUp()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Columns("A:A").Copy
        Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("$C:$C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-3],RC[-1],C[-2])"
        Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't completely see what you are trying to do, but it seems like it might be a job for a pivot table rather than VBA

Comment: I've added some pictures. i want this to be automated because the list will be different every day.

Comment: Have you used `Formulas | Evaluate Formula` to step through your resulting formula to ensure you've got it correct? Additionally, this does sound like a Pivot Table would be a _much_ better option. If you or your users don't want to right-click the pivot table then select `Refresh`, your macro button could kick off a loop that would refresh all the pivot tables on the worksheet. It would probably be much easier, faster and make better use of built in functions instead of trying to rewrite them yourself (which is essentially what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me quite nicely, producing what is intended:

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("C:D").ClearContents
        .Columns("A:A").Copy

        .Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("$C:$C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-3],RC[-1],C[-2])"
        .Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This doenst work either. it only counts the amount of times a product is mentioned in collomn A.

Comment: @PimvandeLuitgaarden - well, "only" counting is actually one step away from "summing". I have edited with `=SUMIF`

Answer (score -1):

Seems you may be trying to conditionally sum Text.